# logging in GWT, configuration via code

Tags: gwt, logging, configuration, log4j, settings

Now i had 2 set of logging framework in my GWT APP, gwt log and log4j. i am having hard time setting the configuration, so i decide to give up setting it via log4j.xml nor lo4j.property as well as in gwt.xml.

I saw some API code which can set log level, Does anyone know how to set appender or handler in code ?

Or if anyone can help me get the GWT Logging working, that would be awesome, currently i found that root logger has debug level INFO and null handler at all, totally different than setting in my gwt.xml

here is gwt.xml code relate to logging:

```
<!-- for gwt logging                                            -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/> 
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINE"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

Comment: To me your question is unclear. Are you trying to configure client-side or server-side logging?  Unless you know something I don't, log4j is not usable on the client side.

Have you checked out these resources?

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging

And 

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

They might be a good start and answering you question

Comment: You could also post you get. XML and log4j.xml files; if there's something wrong with them someone here might be able to help with that.

Comment: @MarkS. just read those article, for better compatibility i would love to use GWT logging only. i just updated the gwt.xml, Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i am finally found what i done wrong, For google web toolkit project, and server side log only, put the log4j.xml configuration file into war/WEB-INFO/classes. and add -dLog4j.debug=true in your launch arguments to see lo4j configuration loading in action.